# ngork does't find a python endpoint

Tags: python, flask, ngrok

https://absolutely-precise-fowl.ngrok-free.app/login where login is an python endpoint, doesn't work where https://absolutely-precise-fowl.ngrok-free.app/login1 where login1 is a html, is working

flask is listening on port 5000

when running   await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
is working as expected, I am logged in to the app,
this is a new app ready to be tested and using ngork is a great way to test how will it work before exposing the server to the internet. As I said, locally the app has been tested (functionally) and it is working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.